# How to infinitely populate a mongoDB model?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to find a way to infinitely populate in mongoDB. I have a Posts collection that has a comments array of object ids. Each comment also has an array of childComment ids. I am able to nest two populates but this commenting system is similar to Reddit in that there can be an infinite number of nested comments.

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .populate({
      path: 'postComments',
      populate: {
        path: 'commentComments'
      }
     })
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(posts => res.json(posts))
    .catch(err => res.status(404)
      .json({ nopostsfound: 'No posts found'}));
});
```

I'm hoping to find a way where the populate of commentComments will continue for as many nested comments as there are. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

This is an inherently problematic database schema. Some changes to the schema will make your task much easier.

Don't store an array of comment IDs in the Post or Comment objects. This will cause problems when the array becomes very large, or when many clients need to update the parent object at once.

Instead, in each Comment object, store the IDs of the Post which it belongs to, as well as of the Comment it is in response to (if any). Then, to load comments for a Post, search for every Comment belonging to that post and perform a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) on the resulting objects.

This schema has a number of major benefits over the one you've described -- the schema is compatible with traditional relational databases, all comments for a post can be retrieved in a single query, and new comments can be added with a single insert query.

Comment: Thank you for your help dusk. Using your advice I added a postId and parentId to each comment. I now fetch all the comments in one query. Haven't implemented the topological sort yet. For the time being key value pairs in a comments slice of state gets the job done: { parentId: [childComments] }.

Answer (score 0):

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
  Post.find()
    .populate([{
      path: 'postComments',
      populate: [{
        path: 'commentComments',
        populate: {
          path: 'childComments'
        }
      }]
     }])
    .sort({ date: -1 })
    .then(posts => res.json(posts))
    .catch(err => res.status(404)
      .json({ nopostsfound: 'No posts found'}));
});
```

You can populate infinitely populate with nested populate.

Comment: Thanks for your help krb. I tried doing this as well but this will only populate the comments for as many levels as populate is included. So if I had 10 nested comments I would need to have 10 nested populates. I was hoping there was a way to simply populate all nested comments by looping or something.